# Duplicate parameters in optimizer's parameter group, what happens

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I realized that the optimizer with which I trained my PyTorch models had repeated parameters, e.g. like this:

```py
model = MyModel()
params = list(model.parameters()) + list(model.parameters()) + list(model.parameters())
optimizer = Adam(params)
```

I have now fixed the issue but I need to understand what was happening before. Was the training being performed normally? Or did each optimizer `step()` update the parameters 3 times?